# How much memory is allocated to Session variables?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, session

I know I can store small values to the `Session`.

Lately in my Visual Studio ASP.NET application, I've learned I can also store larger values, such as a `DataTable`.

This leaves me wondering how much storage the `Session` can store. Does this depend on the browser or the RAM on the PC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET Session is stored on the webserver that is hosting the website.  So the limitation would be how much RAM is on your webserver, not the browser or RAM on the client PC.  So if you have 4 users on your site, and each has 128MB of session, then your webserver is going to have more than 512MB of RAM dedicated to ASP.NET.

I also would be very careful about storing a lot of things in session.  Especially complex types like DataTable.  This is because every time you access that object it has to serialized/deserialized, and this can be very taxing on your webserver's CPU.

I would recommend reading up on some [best practices for ASP.NET Session](http://www.aspnet101.com/2010/10/asp-net-session-state-best-practices/).

Comment: Oh! Good thing I asked. Thanks for the link, too.

Comment: Quick followup for another upvote: I've got a `DataTable` that I am trying to add rows to (think of a shopping cart), but if I declare that `DataTable` in the code behind, every time I test the **ADD** button to add another row to the data, the `DataTable` is **NULL**. What's the best way around this?

Comment: If your DataTable object is being created and accessed from the same ASP.NET page then you can store it in ViewState.  ViewState is stored on the page, so if your DataTable grows very large you could see your page loads grow significantly.  If it's not too large then you can access it through the code behind via the ViewState collection (syntax is similar to Session).